# Google Map Resize

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to implement onclick listener inside onclick of map.
When the user clicked the map, the map will take fullscreen.
My map is 1/4 of the screen.
so that i will take fullscreen when the user click on it.

I tried only this.

```
  map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            }
        });
```

getLayoutParams is not working to set width or height. any other way to do what i want?

Comment: set xml in width and height in map activity. or manage in run time.

Answer (score 0):

This is it worked for me:

```
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() { @Override  public void onMapClick(LatLng point)  {
        LinearLayout mapFrameLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapf);

        if (!isMapOpen)     
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams fullMapParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            if (!isDetailsOpen)
            {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.hide(closedDetailsFragment).commit();
                mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(fullMapParams);
                isMapOpen = true;
                isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap = false;
            }
            else
            {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.hide(openedDetailsFragment).commit();
                mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(fullMapParams);
                isMapOpen = true;
                isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultMapparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 280);
            mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(defaultMapparams);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap)
            {
                fragmentTransaction.show(openedDetailsFragment).commit();               
            }
            else
            {
                fragmentTransaction.show(closedDetailsFragment).commit();
            }
            isMapOpen = false;
        } }   
});
```

Comment: this might actually work.. I'm on out of town, maybe i can try this after i got home. But can this handle Onbackpress? I mean my map fragment is inside a fragment which is dont have onbackpress. When i use backpress the map willbe resized back to original size.

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit(); 
U may try addtobackstack for to handle on back press